# query to divide the column fullname into firstName and lastName columns returned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using Sql Server.
I am trying to write an sql query to divide the column named fullName into firstName and lastName columns. but I keep on getting this error:

```
  Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
  Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

This is my query:

```
 SELECT  CASE
      WHEN (LEN (FullName) - LEN (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', '')) + 1) > 0
      THEN
         Substring (FullName, 1, Charindex (' ', FullName) - 1)
      ELSE
         ''
   END AS FirstName,      
   CASE
      WHEN (LEN (FullName) - LEN (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', '')) + 1) > 0
       THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(FullName),
                   1,
                   CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(FullName)) - 1))
       ELSE FullName
   END AS LastName,email, c.customerid
FROM            Customer c
```

What can be causing this error ? I have verified that there are no fullname records that are empty '' or null. But fullname could hold just a firstname if someone forgot to add their lastname - I am not sure if this could be the issue ?

If I remove the +1:

```
 WHEN (LEN (FullName) - LEN (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', ''))) > 0
```

Then it returns results - but the firstname and lastname columns are both empty even though fullname actually contains the first name but only the first name - for instance 'Seyhan'. How can I fix it so that at least it returns the firstname ?

Comment: This is a classic case where sample data would make things so much more clear

Comment: Rrequired reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: `WHEN (LEN (FullName) - LEN (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', '')) + 1) > 0` why the `+ 1`?

Comment: If there is only a firstname (or last name) then there is no space (`' '`) character in your value, and so `SUBSTRING` generates the error (you omitted) as `0 - 1` = `-1` and you *can't* have the first `-1` characters of a string.

Comment: If I remove the +1 so that the line look like this:
WHEN (LEN (FullName) - LEN (REPLACE (FullName, ' ', ''))) > 0
Then it works - but the firstname and lastname are both empty when fullname contains only the firstname. How can I fix it so that at least it returns the firstname ?

Comment: You could add  `WHEN CHARINDEX (' ',FullName) = 0` to each CASE expression setting it to Fullname for your FirstName and an empty string ('') for you last name like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/viRpOkOW). Any middle initials or names will be ignored.

Comment: thanks Isaac and Charlieface - please leave an answer.

Comment: Do you want an "answer" so you can mark it as correct? My answer is in the dbfiddle link in my previous comment.

Comment: And what should happen if your name is [Keith Allen Haring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Haring), or [David Dwight Eisenhower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_D._Eisenhower) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message itself is self-explanatory and it's clearly saying that you have specified an invalid length parameter to the SUBSTRING function.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('SQL Tutorial', 1, LEN(SUBSTRING('SQL Tutorial',1,(CHARINDEX(' ', 'SQL Tutorial'))))) AS ExtractString;
```

This above query returns First part “SQL”

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_substring

Try using STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator [ , enable_ordinal ] )

```
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', ' ');
```

In a practice run, the preceding SELECT returned following result table:

| value |
| --- |
| Lorem |
| ipsum |
| dolor |
| sit |
| amet. |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16